# Android - openFileOutput writes to ... System Memory on Archos 101

Tags: android, memory

I'm trying to download a file and save it to internal memory. I'm using the following code :

```
FileOutputStream file = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
byte[]           buffer = new byte[4096];
int              len;

while ((len = input.read(buffer, 0, 4096)) > 0)
  file.write(buffer, 0, len);

file.close();
input.close();
```

That is working fine, but the file is not saved into internal memory but into "system memory" (which is limited to 256 Mo), I have seen that by going into the system settings menu (According to documentation openFileOutput() should allow me to write into internal memory).

The path of the file is something like "/data/data/..." with my current code.

I am working on an Archos 101 tablet, with android 2.2.1.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Where are you writing the path for file.Please mention it here.

Comment: I do not specify the path for the file in my code (if that is the question), the path I mentionned in my comment is what I get when I look what is the path of my file after it has been written. I just mentionned it in case it can be of help for answering to my problem.

Comment: Ok it cleared my doubt.Now the openFileOutput will store the file always to the folder `"data/data/<your package name>/files"` path & thats the internal storage of application.

Comment: Ok thanks. But why isn't my internal memory size decreasing when I save the file whereas the "System Memory" (don't know what it really is) is decreasing by the size of the file I'm saving. The same code works well on Samsung Galaxy (it really puts the file into internal memory) but the behaviour seems different on Archos 101.